# C# Dependency Resolution for implicit references

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, nuget, .net-6.0

I'm struggling to find documentation and sources to read through about the different behaviors I have found regarding implicit dependencies.

The different behaviors I have found:

I created a .NET Framework (4.8) Project "A" and another one called "B". "A" is referenced in "B". I install a nuget package e.g. 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt' in "A" I can obviously use it there but I cannot use it in project "B".

```
B -> A -> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
```

Then I tried the same thing with .NET6 Projects. There i can use the nuget package in "A" and "B".

I'm trying to figure out if its something that changed in the switch from .net framework to .net core or maybe its due to the sdk-style projects that are default with newer dotnet versions ?

I have read through documents like this one -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution but it does not seem to mention framework/project differences.

Is there a document where I can read through the different behaviors ? When was this changed ? Is there a way to get the same behavior that .net 6 has in .net framework 4.8 ?

Comment: "maybe its due to the sdk-style projects" - yes, I believe that's relevant. I suggest you use an SDK-style project with .NET 4.8. (It works perfectly well - I haven't used an old-style project for years.)

Answer (score 0):

NuGet has two package management styles, packages.config, and PackageReference, but a project can only use one of these two at a time. packages.config was NuGet first style, available since its first release in 2011. In 2016 PackageReference was added, but since most people don't like breaking changes, the default was never changed. SDK style projects can only be PackageReference, so packages.config is only relevant for non-SDK style projects.

With packages.config, packages are not transitive. Every project is completely independent, and it works more or less the same way as project references. You can try yourself with 3 projects. Project C, that references Project B, can't reference Project A's public APIs, even though Project B can.

PackageReference added in the concept of transitive packages, but NuGet considers projects to be equivalent to packages, so it enables transitive project referencing as well. SDK style projects only support PackageReference, so can't use packages.config. The older style non-SDK style projects default to packages.config (because most people hate breaking changes, so it's effectively impossible to change this default).

As Jon Skeet wrote in a comment, you can still target the .NET Framework from an SDK style project. Here's a complete example of a .NET Framework 4.8.1 class library project

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net481</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

There are a small number of project types that can't be converted to SDK style projects. For those, you can install at least one package using PackageReference (in VS, open options, go to NuGet Package Manager, and on the General options, set "ask on first use" for package management style).  Alternatively, you can do [like the .NET SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/ad13b9d4da70a0fbbd6c84edef2c8d367e80cbc8/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.props#L106-L109) and set `<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>` in your project file. If you don't have any packages.config projects in your repo, then you can [set this in a `Directory.Build.props` file, so it only needs to be set once](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory). PackageReference has other differences compared to packages.config, and this means that .NET Framework ASP.NET projects that use NuGet packages for js and css content can't switch to PackageReference. In this case you just need to install the package in multiple projects.